# Jenkins throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException at end of build on Mac?

Tags: exception, build, jenkins

I am getting:

```
FATAL: Bounds exceeds available space : size=262144, offset=262145
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=262144, offset=262145
at com.sun.jna.Memory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:168)
at com.sun.jna.Memory.getByte(Memory.java:394)
    ...
```

at the end of every build.

Comment: This is great, but you should just phrase this in the form of a question and answer your own question :-)

Comment: I don't think you understand how stackoverflow works. What @Nicholas said was right: phrase this as a question, answer your own question and accept the answer. And please don't beg for upvotes...

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer below and mark as accepted.

Comment: Ok guys - I've done as you suggested. Thanks for the advice. It's a valid question/answer - can you remove your down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in recent builds that causes this, but the work around is to add

```
-Dhudson.util.ProcessTreeKiller.disable=true
```

to the start-up command of the tomcat. One way is to add it to `JAVA_OPTS` in `<tomcat-home>/bin/startup.sh`